# Update apenas em um caractere de uma coluna - Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Tenho uma coluna, onde esta escrito R. TESTE, preciso apenas fazer uma correção deixando para RUA. TESTE, como fazer essa alteração no banco de dados Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão abaixo irá atualizar todos os valores de COLUNA onde o valor comece com `R.`:

```
UPDATE TABELA
SET    COLUNA = REPLACE(COLUNA,'R. ','RUA. ')
WHERE  COLUNA   LIKE 'R. %';
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito Obrigado @OnoSendai.

Comment: Sempre um prazer ajudar, @Diogodgo.

Answer (score 1):

Bom não sei as regras do DBA do seu sistema, mas não é recomendado este tipo de nome para coluna.

Caso sua dúvida seja referente ao registro da coluna de Endereço/Lougradouro:

```
update table
    set [NomeDaColunaDeEndereco] = 'Rua Teste'
[WHERE id = x];
```

Caso sua dúvida seja referente ao nome da coluna:

```
alter table
   tabela
rename column
   [R.TESTE]  
TO
   RUATESTE;
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Ola Tábata, me refiro ao registro mesmo, no caso eu tenho uma unica linha que esta escrito dessa forma, eu preciso corrigir apenas a letra R para RUA. Não seria o caso do alter table não.

Comment: Muito obrigada Diogo, eu entendi errado. :) Bom o Ono deu uma boa solução caso você não tenha o ID, pensei num registro específico :(

Comment: Mas agradeço a ajuda mesmo assim.